# Adding a Cell Reference to a file name

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to save a file using VBA but the file name needs to reference a cell within the Workbook in which I am running the Macro from.

I need to copy data from a tab within an Macro enabled workbook into a new comma separated text file. The name of the text file (output file) should contain a reference to a cell in the Workbook from which the Macro is being ran.

Another issue that I am having is that I would like to change the delimiter in the output file to a pipe delimited file, and not a comma separated file. Is this possible?

This is what I have tried

```
Sheets("Cash Sheet").Select
    Rows("1:100000").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, 
SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
        "C:\Desktop\CashBook_\" & Range("E3") & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlCSV, 
        CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Sheets("Control Sheet").Select
    Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: How do we know what you're doing wrong, we don't know what the problem is!?

Comment: The problem is, the macro does not run because of this incorrect piece of code.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: We also don't know what is in cell `E3`

Comment: I don't get an error message as the macro will not run

Comment: How are you trying to run the macro? Is there a syntax error? Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: Cell "E3" is in the workbook and is a string

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - we don't even know what worksheet E3 is on.

Comment: *What* is the string? Not all file names are valid.

Comment: I ran your original code (it has since been changed) without problem using a blank workbook. Try that, and if that works, it's possible that what you're running into is due to running the code a second time with a workbook that is no longer an .xlsm workbook but instead your .txt file.

Comment: @ John Coleman the string is **201712**

Comment: If you aren't getting any error message, try using `Break in Class Module` in the VBA editor general options. This is probably the most useful setting, but it isn't the default setting.

Comment: @Tony M  The XLSM workbook that the Macro is contained in also contains the Cell that I am referencing

Comment: Thank you for the advice guys, much appreciated. Going forward I will ensure that my questions are more complete and accurate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Desktop\CashBook_\" & Range("E3") & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

The code will reference cell E3 in the new workbook you're trying to save.

To fix, I would put the name of the file as a variable and then pass that to the .SaveAs

```
Dim SaveName As String
   SaveName = Range("A1").Value
...

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\temp\" & SaveName & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: Ok, the Active workbook does not contain the cell reference, the file that the Macro is running from contains the cell reference. How can I change the cell reference from the "Active File" (the file that I am trying to save) to the Workbook that is running the macro?

Comment: You were down voted because you were asking for clarification in the answer space instead of the comments where they belong.  Now this is an answer and so as such I have removed the down vote.

Comment: Sorry @ScottCraner! As I am new user, I am not allowed to comment until my reputation goes above 50!

Comment: I realize the rules, and they are there for a reason.  Please do not use the answers for clarifications.  You will need to get the rep, by answering questions and wait like all the rest of us did.  I realize it is frustrating but you will get voted down using the answers for clarification.

Comment: @TheNumbersMan NB: Make sure the Dim and allocation of name to variable occurs before you reference your new workbook. I.e. that it occurs in the Workbook that has the name in.

Comment: @TheNumbersMan use this to activate a specific workbook  `Windows("WorkbookName").Activate` before `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs...`

Answer (score 1):

If it's in the file containing the macro perhap this

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\Temp\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Whatever").Range("E3").text & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
CreateBackup:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

Range("E3") has a date (12/31/2017 perhaps) in it that you have used cell formatting of `yyyymm` to show `201712`.

You think that you are trying to save as 201712.txt but in fact you are trying to save as 12/31/2017.txt, an illegal filename.

Use the cell's .Text property to use what the cell displays, not the underlying value.

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:= _
    "C:\Desktop\CashBook_\" & Range("E3").Text & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlCSV, 
    CreateBackup:=False
```